# Why is the numeric column treated as a categorical column in Microsoft Learning?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

Learning Microsoft's DP-100 and saw [this notebook](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/ml-basics/blob/master/03%20-%20Classification.ipynb):

The part of its code which I have question with is

```
# Define preprocessing for categorical features (encode the Age column)
categorical_features = [7]
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
```

here is the link for the [entire notebook](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/ml-basics/blob/master/03%20-%20Classification.ipynb) for you to see the full picture. I cannot copy the full pages of code here.

Here is how the data look like:
[image]

My question is: Why is the **DiabetesPedigree** column(which is the 7th column) treated as a **categorical** feature?

To me, it looks nothing different from the rest of other columns(except the Diabetic column).

If DiabetesPedigree could be treated as categorical why not Pregnancies?

What are the rules to tell whether a column of data is numeric or categorical?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the comment in that notebook:

```
# Define preprocessing for categorical features (encode the Age column)
```

It seems that the data you have is different (maybe only in order) to what is used in the notebook as the `Age` column is the eigth column (index seven) in the notebook. See also the cell where data is selected from the input file:

```
# Separate features and labels
features = ['Pregnancies','PlasmaGlucose','DiastolicBloodPressure','TricepsThickness','SerumInsulin','BMI','DiabetesPedigree','Age']
label = 'Diabetic'
X, y = diabetes[features].values, diabetes[label].values
```

Comment: found why the 7th col is `Age`, thanks for pointing it out. But this doesn't answer my question, why Age is considered as a categorical column rather than a numeric column?